# Next.js При попытке вызвать 404 ошибка TypeError: Cannot read property 'object' of undefined

Tags: next.js

Next.js. При попытке вызвать страницу 404 происходит ошибка
TypeError: Cannot read property 'logo_text' of undefined.

У меня есть вложенные страницы
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Пытаюсь вывести страницу 404 для этой вложенности, получаю ошибку
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Проверяю лог. Действительно, в компонент приходит undefined
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Значит пишем условие
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Но ошибка остается
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Проверяю что условие написано в правильном файле для url-а этой вложенности. Исправляю условие чтобы существующая страница отдавала 404
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

В общем непонятно почему эта ошибка вообще происходит, потому что данные для contactInformation всегда доступны с сервера.
И почему даже если contactInformation у нас undefined не срабатывает это условие?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Оказалось что в return getStaticPaths необходимо передать fallback: false,[image: введите сюда описание изображения]